# Invertibility of certain matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Deteremine whether the following matrices are invertible:

(a) $(a_{ij})_{n\times n}$ with $a_{ii}=\pi$ and $a_{ij}\in \mathbb{Q}$ for $i\not=j$.

(b) $\begin{pmatrix}
2003 & 1 & 1 & \cdots &1\\
1 & 2003 &1 & \cdots & 1 \\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & 1&1&\cdots & 2003\\
\end{pmatrix}_{2003 \times 2003}$

I can solve (a) using the fact that $\pi$ is not algebraic and then uses the characteristic equation of the matrix. I wanted to solve (b) similarly but have failed, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not able to see a method using the characteristic equation. But here is another method. 
$A=\begin{pmatrix}
2003 & 1 & 1 & \cdots &1\\
1 & 2003 &1 & \cdots & 1 \\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & 1&1&\cdots & 2003\\
\end{pmatrix}_{2003 \times 2003}$
$O=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots &1\\
1 & 1 &1 & \cdots & 1 \\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & 1&1&\cdots & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}_{2003 \times 2003}$
$A=O -(-2002) I$
$det(A)=det(O-(-2002)I)$
We know that the eigenvalues of $O$ are only $0$ and $2003$.So, $det(A)\not=0$ and hence is invertible.